# How can I make a vertical slider in swift?

Tags: swift, rotation, slider

I was wondering how I can create a vertical slider in swift.

I have tried using `.transform` and then adding a rotate but this returned an exception and rotated the whole screen. I just need a vertical slider.

I was wondering if anyone know of a way to rotate a slider in swift?

Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about **UISlider** :

You were looking in a right direction but probably applied *AffineTransformation* to the wrong item... You should use **UISlider.transform** to change it orientation.
Here is working code (I did add UISlider using InterfaceBuilder):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var verticalSlider: UISlider!{
        didSet{
            verticalSlider.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift 3 you should use CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2))

Comment: Swift 3 with cleaner syntax: `CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi)`

Comment: Actually CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2)

Comment: Even shorter: `CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -.pi/2)`

Answer (score 11):

**Options 1:**

**In Swift 4:**

**-M_PI_2** is deprecated so Use **Double.pi / 2**

```
verticalSlider.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-Double.pi / 2))
```

**OR**

**Options 2:** for All **Objective C and Swift**

```
Key path = layer.transform.rotation.z 
Type     =  String
Value    = -1.570795
```

[image]

**Most Imp Note: before and After keypath No Space**

Answer (score 5):

Use OOP. If you define this rotation as an Extension on UIView, then not only the UIView but also all subclasses that inherit from UIView can be rotated. This of course includes UISlider, but also UILabel, UIButton and about 200? other subclasses... see here
[list of subclasses for UIView](http://www.themusingsofalostprogrammer.com/2010/09/list-of-every-uiview-subclass.html)

```
 extension UIView
 {
    func makeVertical()
    {
         transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2)
    }
 }

  // usage example:
  sldBoilerTemperature.makeVertical()
```

It's good to be aware of inheritance, saves a lot of work. For many Swift extensions to make, it might be a good idea trying to move it upwards in the class hierarchy, like in this example.

Answer (score 1):

Swift-5 Vertical slider with constraints

```
func transformSlider(){
    var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    ControlSlider.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-Double.pi/2))
    ControlSlider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    constraints.append(ControlSlider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.8))
    constraints.append(ControlSlider.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor))
    let sliderWidth = (ControlSlider.frame.height * 0.8)/2
    print(sliderWidth)
    constraints.append(ControlSlider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: (20-sliderWidth)))
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
}
```

Comment: You answer requires adding another 3rd party tool

Comment: Just create a UISlider in the storyboard and create an outlet for it named ControlSlider. No 3rd party items required. Then call this function

Comment: This does not work

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to what Anup Gupta said above, I learnt that you can actually just add the transformation through the attribute inspector. You can add the `layer.transform.rotation.z` to the User Defined runtime attributes as a String with the value -1.570795.

[Adding rotation value straight into attribute inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn5YR.png)