# How to create a Vertical Slider in XCode's Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, swift, interface-builder

I can create a vertical sliders in Swift, as detailed here:[How can I make a vertical slider in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731891/how-can-i-make-a-vertical-slider-in-swift)

But the sliders are only visible at runtime.  How can I create/extend a UISlider to be vertical, yet visible in Interface Builder, so that I can use Autolayout to position them?

Comment: Try a custom view with @IBDesignable that contains your slider.

Comment: You can use autolayout without interface builder.

Comment: It's Not possible Interface Builder you have to write the code. 
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/49668270/5855888](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49668270/5855888)

Comment: There are several implentations on github.  Take a look at this one: https://github.com/jonkykong/VerticalSlider/blob/master/VerticalSlider/Classes/VerticalSlider.swift

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible in **Interface Builder** you have to write the code.

**Options 1:**

**In Swift 4:**

**-M_PI_2** is deprecated so Use **Double.pi / 2**

```
verticalSlider.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-Double.pi / 2))
```

**OR**

**Options 2:** for All **Objective C and Swift**

```
Key path = layer.transform.rotation.z 
Type     =  String
Value    = -1.570795
```

[image]

**Most Imp Note: before and After keypath No Space**

Comment: Can you explain a why the second method with setting `layer.transform.rotation.z` works? How is this actually interpreted by iOS?

Comment: Option 2 is done in Interface Builder and not in a source file, so that makes me happy!

Answer (score 1):

In order to use autolayour to position them, Id follow this guide.
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6Vru1v7DCo][1]

You won't need the beginning as you've already figured that out, but the idea behind getting the auto layouts to work is explained in the last minute or so.

Basically what you want to do is put the slide ball handle in the center. And then you realize that you are going to rotate about that ball. You can then visualize what your constraints need to be. Its hard to explain better in text but the visual representation is nice.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to represent the fader in the interface builder would be to give it a ratio of 1:1.

After the 90° rotation, your component will have the same height and width.